# How to download an encrypted object from S3 and decrypt the same?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have an encrypted object available on S3.

I would like to download it and decrypt it as well.

The object has been encrypted using CMK/KMS algorithm.

Inspite of seeing a few blogs, the steps to download the encrypted object and decrypt it is not clear. Please help.

Comment: The answer depends on how the object was encrypted, and whether it uses server-side encryption or client-side encryption. Look at the object in the console, scroll down to "Server-side encryption settings", and edit your question to show what it says there.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of examples for the service SDKs of how to do this, mainly you need the `kms` [decrypt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kms/decrypt.html) passing a blob param to decrypt your download data.

For example in Node.js, you will need something like this, passing the buffer for the downloaded s3 file:

```
const decryptData = (buffer) => {
    const params = {
        CiphertextBlob: buffer
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        kms.decrypt(params, (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data.Plaintext);
        })
    })
}
```

To do this using the aws cli you can use the following command:

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://${ENCRYPTED_S3_FILE} --query Plaintext --output text \
    | base64 --decode
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using AWS CLI?

Comment: I updated the question to add an example with the cli